# Android: Updating ImageView from Service, only if the Activity is running

Tags: android, android-activity, service, imageview

I have a service triggering doing some calculations on bitmaps in a separate thread.
In the memory I have many bitmaps to be processed, and therefore I have a problem.

When there is only the service running (activity is paused/hidden/whatever) I want to process these bitmaps without changing any UI.
But only when the Activity is on the top (visible/active/running) I want to refresh ImageView to display currently processed bitmap (it will be 5 FPS).

So how can I check whether the Activity is running? And how can I easily update the ImageView from the service? (I can pass a bitmap, or a file path).
Is it advised, to bind the service to activity? Use Messenger?

Comment: When you start your Activity bind to your Service and use "bound local service" pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I check whether the Activity is running?

Don't.

> And how can I easily update the ImageView from the service?

Use an event bus implementation, like `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, or Square's Otto. Have the service raise an event when the bitmap is ready. Have your activity register for the events when the activity is the foreground and unregister when it is in the background. Then, the service does not care what is going on with the activity -- the event bus handles all of that.

Here are implementations of this pattern for:

- [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager)
- [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot)
- [Square's Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto)

> Is it advised, to bind the service to activity?

There really is no such concept in Android.

Comment: This post seems to be helpful. I'm trying it now.
Pardon me, I am an extreme beginner with Android (also with asking on StackOverflow), and not so experienced in Java, so I feel kinda lost at this moment.

I'm trying to do something else. How can I easily loop over a set of thousands of Bitmaps to be processed and where to locate this loop? Where in the Service exactly?

Is it a good way, to use my Runnable class object created in the Service, with its own Thread for calculations of each Bitmap?
(App should go through many bitmaps from the medical examination, search pathologies, (...)

Comment: @PiotrKopczyński: I cannot tell you "where in the service exactly", other than it needs to be on a background thread.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I find your answers very useful. I was not too precised, in the service - I meant at which moment of its lifecycle (I want to constantly send work request from the service [probably in a loop] to calculate things in another thread, while the service is running). So should I place this loop in onStartCommand?

Comment: @PiotrKopczyński: Again, I cannot tell you where it should go, other than on a background thread. You could start the thread in `onCreate()`. You could start the thread in `onStartCommand()`. You could start the thread from an interface exposed by `onBind()`. And so on.